# Image from manually created byte[]

Tags: c#, image, arrays, memorystream

I want to create an image from `byte[]` that I create manually, but I get a JIT error

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at CreateBitmapFromStream.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Data\C#-Workspace\CreateBitmapFromStream\CreateBitmapFromStream\Form1.cs:line 35
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
...
```

Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var data = new byte[20*10];
  for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
  {
    if (i < 100)
      data[i] = 0x15;
    else
      data[i] = 0x99;
  }

  using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
  {
    var img = Image.FromStream(ms, true, true);  
    panel1.BackgroundImage = img;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? As far as I know, `Image.FromStream` reads an image encoded in a given format (ex: bmp, jpg, png). Looks like you are trying to create an image by writing pixel by pixel. What do the values `0x15` and `0x99` represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image is constructed according a certain format.

It's not just a sequence of pixels. If you want to draw pixels, use the `Bitmap` class provided by `System.Drawing`

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(1, 1);
b.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Gray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate images you should use the BitmapData class. With the BitmapData you can write pixel data into an bitmap/image.

Here's an example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.scan0.aspx